# Introduce zero values between successive lines in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
164.91 0               
164.96 32 
165.01 0 
165.11 0 
165.16 4
166.16 0")
```

I want to introduce zero values in the second column (dd$V2) to create a new dataframe where the difference between successive lines in the first colomn (dd$V1) will be equal to 0.01.

The result must be:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
164.91 0
164.92 0
164.93 0
164.94 0
164.95 0               
164.96 32 
164.97 0 
...")
```

Comment: Please provide a more realistic example, the first `dd` does not fulfill your requirements (the difference is always greater than `0.01`).

Comment: I'm 95% sure i've stumbled upon a function, and I think it was a base one, that builds a sequence from min value to max using the smaller available interval, but I can't seem to remember its name... It'd made all those solutions much sexier (though probably a bit less efficient).

Answer (score 3):

Merge with a dataframe that has all the intermediate values for V1.

```
dd2 <- merge( data.frame(V1=round( seq(head(dd$V1,1), tail(dd$V1,1), by=0.01), digits=2) ), 
              dd, 
              by="V1", all.x=TRUE)
> head(dd2)
      V1 V2
1 164.91  0
2 164.92 NA
3 164.93 NA
4 164.94 NA
5 164.95 NA
6 164.96 32

> dd2$V2[is.na(dd2$V2)] <- 0
> head(dd2)
      V1 V2
1 164.91  0
2 164.92  0
3 164.93  0
4 164.94  0
5 164.95  0
6 164.96 32
```

Comment: Aren't any of these methods that use `seq(..., by=.01)` going to have a precision problem? For example `any(seq(164.01, 164.05, by=0.01)==164.02)` returns FALSE which is probably going to be a problem when merging.

Comment: @MrFlick `seq` doesn't have a precision problem. `164.02` does. Whether or not that's an issue depends on what you're using it for. The solution isn't to, e.g., represent the values as integers by effectively multiplying everything by 100, it's to use a logical test that has a tolerance in it.

Comment: If there were a sequence problem (which at the moment I'm not seeing) we could solve it with `round`. Agree we could have pulled first and last of V1 to specify the limits of sequence..

Comment: or better, (than `round` to solve a floating point problem if it comes up) with `any(abs(seq(164.01, 164.05, by = 0.01) - 164.02) > .Machine$double.eps^0.5)`

Comment: which( seq(164.50, 164.99, by=0.01) != as.numeric( paste0( "164.",50:99) )  ) # integer(0)  But then there were a bunch in hte range 165.10-165.99

Comment: `which( seq(165.01, 165.99, by=0.01) != as.numeric( paste0( "165.",01:99) ) )`. These are all in the range here, but again, I think floating point issues are best resolved by not using logical comparisons that don't have a tolerance in them when trying to compare floats. Because, again, it's not that `164.02` is the correct value and `164.01 + 0.01` is not. Neither of them are.

Comment: The problem here is the implicit use of equality by the `merge` function (actually probably `match`).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? You want to fill in the implicitly missing values in `V1`. A good tool for this is `tidyr::complete`. The `V1` argument specifies the full range of potential values that `V1` can take, and the `fill` argument specifies what to fill in for `V2` in rows that didn't already exist in the data.

```r
dd <- read.table(text="
164.91 0               
                 164.96 32 
                 165.01 0 
                 165.11 0 
                 165.16 4
                 166.16 0")

library(tidyr)
dd %>%
  complete(
    V1 = seq(min(V1), max(V1), by = 0.01),
    fill = list(V2 = 0)
    )
#> # A tibble: 126 x 2
#>       V1    V2
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   164.91  0
#> 2   164.92  0
#> 3   164.93  0
#> 4   164.94  0
#> 5   164.95  0
#> 6   164.96 32
#> 7   164.97  0
#> 8   164.98  0
#> 9   164.99  0
#> 10  165.00  0
#> # ... with 116 more rows
```

Created on 2018-03-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
dd <- read.table(text="
164.91 0               
                 164.96 32 
                 165.01 0 
                 165.11 0 
                 165.16 4
                 166.16 0")

V1 <- seq(min(dd$V1), max(dd$V1), by = 0.01)
V1 <- V1[!V1 %in% dd$V1]
dd <- rbind(dd, cbind(V1, rep(0, length(V1))))
dd[order(dd$V1), ]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is a pretty convoluted way to do this. You're creating `V1`, and then pulling parts out and putting them back in. Just create the new data frame with `V1` and assign the `V2` values to the appropriate index.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the actual data to a data column with all potential values of `V1` and fill missing values with zero. Here's a `tidyverse` version of that:

```
library(tidyverse)

dd_new = with(dd, data.frame(V1=seq(min(V1), max(V1), 0.01))) %>% 
  full_join(dd) %>% 
  replace_na(list(V2=0))
```

Comment: if you're going to use `tidyverse` you could use `tidyr::replace_na`